# spyOn $rootScope results in $scope is also spied on

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, mocking, jasmine

I have both `$rootScope` and `$scope` setup to listen to certain events. In the unit test (Jasmine) I would like to test controller's `$scope.$on` handler, but not `$rootScope.$on` which is out of the testing scope. So, I tried to spyOn `$rootScope.$on` to make it call a fake function with below code

```
 $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
 $scope = $rootScope.$new();
 spyOn($rootScope, '$on').andCallFake(function () { }); //let $rootScope skip the $on handler
```

Unfortunetaly, I found the code results in the `$scope` be also spied on which is not expected.

Any solution on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that $scope inherit from $rootScope and share the same '$on'.

The only solution I can see is to set $on function on $scope object directly (this way $scope will not inherit $on function) :

```
// Affect $on function on $scope object
// This way $scope has its own $on function
$scope.$on = $rootScope.$on;

// Spy $on function on $rootScope only
spyOn($rootScope, '$on');
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dv5TA/1

Comment: Oh, $scope.$on is inherited from $rootScope, thanks!